# OSError: [WinError 433] A device which does not exist was specified: 'csv_files'

Tags: python, pandas, read-csv

I am trying to troubleshoot this problem which appears to be intermittent. the function is called once per hour.

- sometimes the code runs for several days (hundreds of loops)
- other times it runs for just a day (20 or so loops)

```
OSError: [WinError 433] A device which does not exist was specified: 'csv_files'
```

I trace the code back to this function, which sometimes returns an empty dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

def get_existing_df(symbol:str)-> pd.DataFrame:
    '''
    check if file exists & get the the existing dataframe for a given symbol
    
    args:
        symbol (str): the ticker symbol

    return (df, last_trade):
        df: (DataFrame) of the last trades (empty df if no trades)    
        
    
    '''
    file_name = 'csv_files/all_trades_' + symbol + '.csv'

    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, index_col=0)
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    return df
```

The code uses a relative path. I can also confirm the obvious:

1. the path exists
2. the file exists
3. i believe that i have permission (the full path is my local google drive).

But every now and again the method gives me an empty dataframe, which breaks the code (with the above error).

What is causing this and how can i prevent this ?

Comment: Perhaps at this moment data is being synchronized with cloud storage and therefore the file is not available.

Comment: @СергейКох,  this is what i am thinking.   I might propose a solution that checks the internet connection first in that respect.

Comment: `the full path is my local google drive` Is this the actual *local* folder, or the virtual drive shown by Google Drive?

Comment: There are ways to retrieve the actual file or sheet from Google Drive, the service, rather than the local cache.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, a good suggestion: i could sync it, but it is not synced on purpose and therefore everything is in the cloud...

Comment: There's your problem then. There's no real device to read from. Instead of depending on Google Sync, you can use `gspread`, `google-drive`, `fsspec` or another package to list the files and retrieve the ones you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the file and path (to file) exist, it is likely to be the connection.

So, I propose the following additional check which uses the `socket` module to check the connection:

```py
import socket


def is_internet_connected():
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80), timeout=3)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

connected = is_internet_connected()
print('checking connection:', connected)
```

This checks the internet connection and if it is down for more than 3 seconds, then returns `False`.

This means that the code can be avoided (`if not connected:`) in the event that the connection is down.